# Extract all content (including HTML) from a div class using PHP

Tags: php, dom, extract

Example HTML...

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="rsheader"><b>Header Content</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="rstext">Some text (Most likely will contain lots of HTML</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to convert a page of HTML into a templated version of that HTML page. The HTML page is made up of several boxes, each with a header (refered to in the above code as "rsheader") and some text (refered to in the above code as "rstext").

I'm trying to write a PHP script to retrieve the HTML page maybe using file_get_contents and then to extract whatever content is within the rsheader and rstext divs. Basically I don't know how to! I've tried experimenting with DOM but I don't know it too well and although I did manage to extract the text, it ignored any HTML.

My PHP...

```
<?php

$html = '<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<table>
<tr>
    <td class="rsheader"><b>Header Content</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="rstext">Some text (Most likely will contain lots of HTML</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml($html);
$xpath = new DomXpath($dom);
$div = $xpath->query('//*[@class="rsheader"]')->item(0);
echo $div->textContent;

?>
```

If I do a print_r($div) I see this...

```
DOMElement Object
    (
    [tagName] => td
    [schemaTypeInfo] => 
    [nodeName] => td
    [nodeValue] => Header Content
    [nodeType] => 1
    [parentNode] => (object value omitted)
    [childNodes] => (object value omitted)
    [firstChild] => (object value omitted)
    [lastChild] => (object value omitted)
    [previousSibling] => 
    [nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
    [attributes] => (object value omitted)
    [ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
    [namespaceURI] => 
    [prefix] => 
    [localName] => td
    [baseURI] => 
    [textContent] => Header Content
    )
```

As you can see there are no HTML tags within the textContent node which leaves me to believe I'm going about it the wrong way :(

Really hoping someone might be able to give me some help with this...

Thanks in advance

Paul

Answer (score 2, accepted):

X-Path is probably a bit more a sledgehammer than you need for this task. I would try using DOMDocument's [getElementById() method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementbyid.php) instead. An example is below, which was adapted from [this post](http://www.codekites.com/php-tutorial-parsing-html-with-domdocument/).

NOTE: Updated to use tag and class names instead of element IDs.

```
function getChildHtml( $node ) 
{
    $innerHtml= '';
    $children = $node->childNodes;

    foreach( $children as $child )
    {
        $innerHtml .= sprintf( '%s%s', $innerHtml, $child->ownerDocument->saveXML( $child ) );
    }

    return $innerHtml;
}

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHtml( $html );

// Gather all table cells in the document.
$cells = $dom->getElementsByTagName( 'td' );

// Loop through the collected table cells looking for those of class 'rsheader' or 'rstext'.
foreach( $cells as $cell )
{
    if( $cell->getAttribute( 'class' ) == 'rsheader' )
    {
        $headerHtml = getChildHtml( $cell );
        // Do something with header html.
    }

    if( $cell->getAttribute( 'class' ) == 'rstext' )
    {
        $textHtml = getChildHtml( $cell );
        // Do something with text html.
    }
}
```

Comment: Changing to ID works perfectly if only it was absolutely true that the HTML page would only have one box on it. As it will have more than one...I can't use id="rsheader" for each one.

Comment: okay, so will the elements you are searching for always be of the same tag name? Will they also have predictable class names? If so, switching out the getElementById function with getElementsByTagName could work to grab a list of possible elements. Those elements could then be inspected to see if they are of the correct class(es). If that assumption holds true, let me know and I'll update the answer.

Comment: Yes the elements I am searching for will always have the same names. Each box has a header and a text area, header is "rsheader" and text area is "rstext". Thanks

Comment: Good deal. Check out the updated code to see if it works for you.

Comment: Great stuff, thank you very much for that Thomas, helps me out a lot!! Thanks m8

*Edit*
Works too!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this answer and use it as guideline:
[retrieving specific data from a website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12746579/retrieving-specific-data-from-a-website/12746602#12746602)

If you need detailed help I am here to help.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your offer of help. I did look at your possible solution but it involved uploading a 3rd party PHP class which at this moment I don't need but thanks anyway. Paul